# How did the Dwarves reproduce?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, dwarves

Aulë created the first 7 Dwarven fathers, from whom 7 Dwarven clans rose. But how did they reproduce into even more clans, if it's known that the first Dwarves were men, and Dwarves reproduce sexually?

**Duplicate**
This question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76327/in-the-hobbit-what-were-the-origins-of-the-dwarves) because my question asks how did dwarves reproduced if in the beginning there were no female dwarves, while [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76327/in-the-hobbit-what-were-the-origins-of-the-dwarves) asks the general origin of dwarves, so please remove the duplicate flag.

Comment: The short answer is that they took wives, indicating that wives were created at much the same time.

Comment: 6 of the first seven Dwarven Fathers were laid to rest with wives. Durin, the first Dwarf to be created, was laid to rest on his own. There are only 7 Dwarven families, but more groups of those families.

Comment: Perhaps Tolkien saw no problem introducing the same confusion found in the Bible: The first humans (Adam and Eve) had two sons (Cain and Abel). Cain killed Abel and then somehow found a woman to marry.

Comment: They were created, they inter-mingled and [life... er... found a way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMjQ3hA9mEA).

Comment: Wasn't God involved in that whole thing at the time?

Comment: Eru ("God") only gave sentient life to the original 13 dwarves created by Äule.

Comment: @Valorum where was I implying that dwarves are related to men? The wives explain it, I was not aware there were any.

Comment: @Benedictus - I've addressed that in my (now-deleted) comment. You said the first dwarves were men. That's ambiguous.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate not because the two questions are the same, but because the answer to the linked question also answers your question.

Comment: @CHEESE I believe this should not be considered duplicate as the answer only covers the question partialy, and is targeted to answer a much broader question. According to this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled indeed, a question CAN BE considered duplicate if it has "same (potential) answers", but that's not the case as the answers are not the same.

Comment: @Benedictus This may be a matter of opinion, but IMO the accepted answer to that question answers yours, which makes it a dupe.